# Spawning a new terminal and opening vim

Tags: c++, c, fork, xterm

What I'm trying to achieve is to open a new terminal from a C/C++ program and run vim. I'm doing this by forking and execing "xterm -e vim [fname]". Try as I might, I can't seem to get xterm to understand what it is I want it to do.

Below is the relevant code segment:

```
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid){
        //parent
        int retstat;
        waitpid (pid, &retstat, 0);
    }else{
        //child
        
        char* ifname_cchararr = (char*)malloc(ifname.length() + 1);
        strcpy (ifname_cchararr, ifname.c_str());
        char* const argv[4] = {"-e", "vim", ifname_cchararr, NULL};
       // std::cout << ifname_cchararr<<std::endl;
        execvp ("xterm", argv);
    }
```

Running the program results in xterm complaining:

> -e : Explicit shell already was /usr/bin/vim
>
> -e : bad command line option "testfile"

I get the feeling I've messed up argc somehow, but I'm confused, because running the following in an xterm window:

> xterm -e vim testfile

works perfectly fine.

Please enlighten me!

Comment: Add `xterm` as first argument to your `argv`.

Comment: @tkausl
oh dearie me. i thought it was handled by the function already. what a silly error.

can you make a short answer so I may accept and upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `xterm` as first argument in `argv`. It may seems a bit weird, that you have to add the program-name to `argv`, since you already tell `execvp` which program you're calling, but thats how it is. For more information to *why*, see this recently asked question on Unix & Linux: [Why does argv include the program name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315812/why-does-argv-include-the-program-name)